# Receber String via Bluetooth e printar em uma caixa de texto

Tags: java, android, bluetooth

Estou com um código Java que adaptei para receber uma string via bluetooth e ao executá-lo no Android Studio não apresenta erros. Contudo, no app ao clicar no botão "Iniciar" para ir na Main2Activity (Onde se encontra o código em questão), apresenta o erro "App X parou".

Segue abaixo o código, caso alguém consiga me ajudar ou possua um outro exemplo que posso usá-lo, agradeço.

Obs.: A conexão do bluetooth está funcionando sem problemas.

```
package com.hlp.bluetoothfinal;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothSocket;
import android.os.Bundle;

import com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton;
import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar;

import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Message;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText textView;
    private EditText textView2;

    private static final int MESSAGE_READ = 3;

    ConnectedThread connectedThread;

    Handler mHandler;
    StringBuilder dadosBluetooth = new StringBuilder( );



    @SuppressLint( "WrongViewCast" )
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate( savedInstanceState );
        setContentView( R.layout.activity_main2 );

        textView = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.textView );

        textView2 = (EditText) findViewById( R.id.textView2 );

        mHandler = new Handler(  ){ // Função

            @Override
            public void handleMessage(@NonNull Message msg) { //metodo

                if(msg.what == MESSAGE_READ) { //

                    String recebidos = (String) msg.obj; // receber dado

                    dadosBluetooth.append(recebidos); // juntar dados

                    int fimInformacao = dadosBluetooth.indexOf("}"); //vendo se a informação está completa

                    if(fimInformacao > 0){ // chegou o final

                        String dadosCompletos = dadosBluetooth.substring(0, fimInformacao ); //dadosCompletos, verifica se tem o inicio { e o fim }

                        int tamInformacao = dadosCompletos.length(); // capturando o tamanho inteiro da informação

                        if(dadosBluetooth.charAt(0) == '{') {  // se a posição zero for igual { então

                            String dadosFinais = dadosBluetooth.substring(1, tamInformacao); // a dados finais recebe desde a posição 1 até o tamanho da informação

                            //Log.d("Recebidos", dadosFinais);

                            textView.setText(dadosFinais);
                        }

                        dadosBluetooth.delete(0, dadosBluetooth.length());
                    }
                }
            }

        };
```

Comment: Não da para saber qual o problema. Precisamos de mais informações, por exemplo qual as versões dos SDK em que o código foi compilado e executado, modelos dos dispositivos emulados e testados, relatórios de erros e alertas no emulador e relatórios de erros e alertas no dispositivo.

Answer (score 0):

Eu conheço essa forma de fazer o recebimento de dados mas tu não foi claro sobre os seguintes pontos:
- Como tu sabe que ta funcionando se o app para antes de chegar na activity onde o código com o handler está,

- Se na activity que tem o botão iniciar possui algo além deste botão.

Vou sugerir o que deve ser feito e com base no teu feedback vou editar a minha resposta espero não ser advertido pela moderação.

1º. Conecte o aparelho em modo desenvolvedor e clique em run para instalar.ja durante a instalação aperte as teclas ALT+6 para abrir o logcat.Na janela do logcat selecione a opção error(segue print)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

agora todo erro que ocorrer será mostrado nessa tela.

Assim que instala clique em INICIAR no teu app para que ocorra o erro.
Como isso voce vai no logcat e verifica onde foi marcado o erro. A indicação estará em azul e contem informação do nome da activity e da linha responsavel pelo erro alem do nome do erro.

Com esse procedimento vais poder fazer a correção.

A causa provável é um nullPointException ou na activity que contem o botão INICIAR ou na activity que está com a thread de conexão pois mesmo que a IDE não dê o alerta em vermelho sobre erro, os chamados warnings que sao as marcações em amarelo podem trazer algum tipo de problema mas nem sempre o que pode ser o seu caso.

Acredito que o erro seja em uma supressão que tem que ser feita no mHandler pois da forma como ele está pode causar fuga de memória, porém aguardo a resposta sobre o erro antes de te instruir.